# How can I integrate Codeigniter auto-completion on Sublime Text 2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sublimetext2

Sublime Text is one of the best editor I've ever saw. I'd like to use it for my codeigniter projects.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/MikeCase/SublimeText-2-Snippets

You can also create your own snippets in Sublime, Notepad++... a lot of text editors have this ability now.